# Finding matching interval(s) in pandas Intervalindex

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

There's this interesting API called `Intervalindex` new in 0.20 that lets you create an index of intervals.

Given some sample data:

```
data = [(893.1516130000001, 903.9187099999999),
 (882.384516, 893.1516130000001),
 (817.781935, 828.549032)]
```

You can create the index like this:

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(data)

print(idx)
IntervalIndex([(893.151613, 903.91871], (882.384516, 893.151613], (817.781935, 828.549032]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

An interesting property of `Interval`s is that you can perform interval checks with `in`:

```
print(y[-1])
Interval(817.78193499999998, 828.54903200000001, closed='right')

print(820 in y[-1])
True

print(1000 in y[-1])
False
```

I would like to know how to apply this operation to the entire index. For example, given some number `900`, how could I retrieve a boolean mask of intervals for which this number fits in?

I can think of:

```
m = [900 in y for y in idx]
print(m)
[True, False, False]
```

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: I'm not aware of, is something amiss with your way?

Comment: @Zero It seems like a useful function to have, so I thought there'd be something of the sort. The only thing amiss with the list comprehension is the loop ;-/

Comment: @Bharathshetty I am a noob. I don't know what's good and what's bad!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ why does get_loc doesnt work with datetimes

Comment: @Bharath It should... I'm not experienced enough with this API to tell you why :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are interested in performance, an IntervalIndex is optimized for searching. using `.get_loc` or `.get_indexer` uses an internally built IntervalTree (like a binary tree), which is constructed on first use.

```
In [29]: idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(data*10000)

In [30]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 idx.map(lambda x: 900 in x)
92.8 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

In [40]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 idx.map(lambda x: 900 in x)
42.7 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

# construct tree and search
In [31]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 idx.get_loc(900)
4.55 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

# subsequently
In [32]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 idx.get_loc(900)
137 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

# for a single indexer you can do even better (note that this is
# dipping into the impl a bit
In [27]: %timeit np.arange(len(idx))[(900 > idx.left) & (900 <= idx.right)]
203 µs ± 1.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Note that .get_loc() returns an indexer (which is actually more useful than a boolean array, but they are convertible to each other).

```
In [38]: idx.map(lambda x: 900 in x)
    ...: 
Out[38]: 
Index([ True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       ...
       False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype='object', length=30000)

In [39]: idx.get_loc(900)
    ...: 
Out[39]: array([29997,  9987, 10008, ..., 19992, 19989,     0])
```

Returning a boolean array is converted to an array of indexers

```
In [5]: np.arange(len(idx))[idx.map(lambda x: 900 in x).values.astype(bool)]
Out[5]: array([    0,     3,     6, ..., 29991, 29994, 29997])
```

This is what .get_loc() and .get_indexer() return:

```
In [6]: np.sort(idx.get_loc(900))
Out[6]: array([    0,     3,     6, ..., 29991, 29994, 29997])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is just amazing. So, just so I’ve understood, get_loc builds a tree that is internally cached for faster searches later?

Comment: Also, you mentioned that they are convertible to each other. How exactly does the second output map to the first?

Comment: yes an IntervalTree is built internally, this is the way of indexing; we normally build a hashtable for other index types to do lookups, this structure yield lots of benefits here though. Updated with how to convert between indexers.

Comment: In newer versions of Pandas (2.0+) it seems like `get_loc` now only accepts and returns scalars, and `get_indexer` now only accepts and returns sequences. `get_loc([900])` is an error, as is `get_indexer(900)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for speed, you can use left and right of idx i.e getting lower bound and upper bound from the range then check if number falls between the bounds i.e

```
list(lower <= 900 <= upper for (lower, upper) in zip(idx.left,idx.right))
```

Or

```
[(900 > idx.left) & (900 <= idx.right)]
```

```
[True, False, False]
```

For small data

```
%%timeit
list(lower <= 900 <= upper for (lower, upper) in zip(idx.left,idx.right))
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.26 µs per loop

%%timeit
[900 in y for y in idx]
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.26 µs per loop
```

For large data

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(data*10000)

%%timeit
list(lower <= 900 <= upper for (lower, upper) in zip(idx.left,idx.right))
10 loops, best of 3: 29.2 ms per loop

%%timeit
[900 in y for y in idx]
10 loops, best of 3: 64.6 ms per loop
```

This method beats your solution for large data.

Comment: I think they are not documented yet but you can see the code  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/indexes/interval.py#L442

Comment: Jeff is one of the core developers of pandas. His word is law ... literally... but thanks for understanding :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map`:

```
idx.map(lambda x: 900 in x)
#Index([True, False, False], dtype='object')
```

Timings:

```
%timeit [900 in y for y in idx]
#100000 loops, best of 3: 3.76 µs per loop

%timeit idx.map(lambda x: 900 in x)
#10000 loops, best of 3: 48.7 µs per loop

%timeit map(lambda x: 900 in x, idx)
#100000 loops, best of 3: 4.95 µs per loop
```

Obviously, comprehension is the fastest but builtin `map` doesn't fall too far behind.

Results even out when we introduce more data, to be precise 10K times more data:

```
%timeit [900 in y for y in idx]
#10 loops, best of 3: 26.8 ms per loop

%timeit idx.map(lambda x: 900 in x)
#10 loops, best of 3: 30 ms per loop

%timeit map(lambda x: 900 in x, idx)
#10 loops, best of 3: 29.5 ms per loop
```

As we see, builtin `map` comes very close to `.map()` so - lets see what happens with 10 times even more data:

```
%timeit [900 in y for y in idx]
#1 loop, best of 3: 270 ms per loop

%timeit idx.map(lambda x: 900 in x)
#1 loop, best of 3: 299 ms per loop

%timeit map(lambda x: 900 in x, idx)
#1 loop, best of 3: 291 ms per loop
```

Conclusion:

comprehension is the winner but not so distinct on larger amounts of data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you prove to me that a map is better than the list comprehension? I'd love to see timings on this, if you don't mind! With some large data too.

Comment: comprehension is faster :)

Comment: Very disappointing. I liked your answer. Still, I'd love to see the timings.

Answer (score 0):

using NumPy

```
import numpy as np
data = [(893.1516130000001, 903.9187099999999),
         (882.384516, 893.1516130000001),
         (817.781935, 828.549032)]    
q = 900
# The next line broadcast q and tell if q is within the intervals/ranges defined in data (using numpy)
np.logical_xor(*(np.array(data) - q > 0).transpose())
```

Comment: try to add some context to boost answer quality. EoR.