# Searching a particular value in a range among two columns python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have two csv files.Depending upon the value of a cell in csv file 1 I should be able to search that value in a column  of csv file 2 and get he corresponding value from other column in csv file 2.
I am sorry if this very confusing.It will probably get clear by illustration

CSV file 1

```
Car   Mileage
 A       8
 B       6
 C       10
```

CSV file 2

```
Score  Mileage(Min)    Mileage(Max)
 1       1                 3
 2       4                 6
 3       7                 9
 4       10                12 
 5       13                15
```

And my desired output CSV file is something like this

```
Car    Mileage     Score
 A       8           3
 B       6           2
 C       10          4
```

Car A is given a score of 3 depending upon its mileage 8 and then looking that mileage in csv file 2 in what range it falls and then getting corresponding score value for that range.
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *As of writing this, the current stable release is v0.21.*

To read your files, use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) -

```
df0 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

df0

  Car  Mileage
0   A        8
1   B        6
2   C       10

df1

   Score  Mileage(Min)  Mileage(Max)
0      1             1             3
1      2             4             6
2      3             7             9
3      4            10            12
4      5            13            15
```

To find the Score, use [`pd.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) by calling `IntervalIndex.from_tuples`. This should be really fast -

```
v = df1.loc[:, 'Mileage(Min)':'Mileage(Max)'].apply(tuple, 1).tolist()
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(v, closed='both') # you can also use `from_arrays`


df0['Score'] = df1.iloc[idx.get_indexer(df0.Mileage.values), 'Score'].values
df0

  Car  Mileage  Score
0   A        8      3
1   B        6      2
2   C       10      4
```

Other methods of creating an `IntervalIndex` are outlined [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_tuples.html#pandas.IntervalIndex.from_tuples).

To write your result, use [`pd.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) -

```
df0.to_csv('file3.csv')
```

---

Here's a high level outline of what I've done here.

1. First, read in your CSV files
2. Use `pd.IntervalIndex` to build an interval index *tree*. So, searching is now logarithmic in complexity.
3. Use [`idx.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.1/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) to find the index of each value in the tree
4. Use the index to locate the `Score` value in `df1`, and assign this back to `df0`. Note that I call `.values`, otherwise, the values will be misaligned when assigning back.
5. Write your result back to CSV

For more information on `Intervalindex`, take a look at this SO Q/A - [Finding matching interval(s) in pandas Intervalindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364710/finding-matching-intervals-in-pandas-intervalindex)

---

Note that `IntervalIndex` is new in `v0.20`, so if you have an older version, make sure you update your version with

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IntervalIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#intervalindex), new in version `0.20.0+`:

First create DataFrames by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
```

Create `IntervalIndex` by [`from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['Mileage(Min)'], df2['Mileage(Max)'], 'both')

print (s)
IntervalIndex([[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9], [10, 12], [13, 15]]
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

Select `Mileage` values by intervalindex and set to new column by array created by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html), because else indices are not aligned and get:

> TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

```
df1['Score'] = df2.set_index(s).loc[df1['Mileage'], 'Score'].values
print (df1)
  Car  Mileage  Score
0   A        8      3
1   B        6      2
2   C       10      4
```

And last write to file by [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df1.to_csv('file3.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup

```
data  = [(1,1,3), (2,4,6), (3,7,9), (4,10,12), (5,13,15)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Score','MMin','MMax'])

car_data = [('A', 8), ('B', 6), ('C', 10)]
car = pd.DataFrame(car_data, columns=['Car','Mileage'])

def find_score(x, df):
    result = -99
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if x >= row.MMin and x <= row.MMax:
            result = row.Score
    return result

car['Score'] = car.Mileage.apply(lambda x: find_score(x, df))
```

Which yields

```
In [58]: car
Out[58]:
  Car  Mileage  Score
0   A        8      3
1   B        6      2
2   C       10      4
```

Comment: While not an incorrect answer, this is probably the slowest of the lot...

Comment: Yes, I didn't know about IntervalIndex. Stackoverflow is a good way to learn more!