# How to vectorize a loop through pandas series when values are used in slice of another series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, vectorization, series

Suppose I have two series of timestamps which are pairs of start/end times for various 5 hour ranges. They are not necessarily sequential, nor are they quantized to the hour.

```
import pandas as pd

start = pd.Series(pd.date_range('20190412',freq='H',periods=25))

# Drop a few indexes to make the series not sequential
start.drop([4,5,10,14]).reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

# Add some random minutes to the start as it's not necessarily quantized
start = start + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(59,size=len(start)),unit='T')

end = start + pd.Timedelta('5H')
```

Now suppose that we have some data that is timestamped by minute, over a range that encompasses all start/end pairs.

```
data_series = pd.Series(data=np.random.randint(20, size=(75*60)), 
                        index=pd.date_range('20190411',freq='T',periods=(75*60)))
```

We wish to obtain the values from the `data_series` within the range of each `start` and `end` time. This can be done naively inside a loop

```
frm = []
for s,e in zip(start,end):
    frm.append(data_series.loc[s:e].values)
```

As we can see this naive approach loops over each pair of `start` and `end` dates, gets the values from data.

However this implementation is slow if `len(start)` is large. Is there a way to perform this sort of logic leveraging `pandas` vector functions?

I feel it is almost like I want to to apply `.loc` with a vector or `pd.Series` rather than a single `pd.Timestamp`?

***EDIT***

Using `.apply` is no more/marginally more efficient than using the naive `for` loop. I was hoping to be pointed in direction of a pure vector solution

Comment: In reality how large are the two DataFrames?

Comment: `len(data_series)` ~ between 10^5 and 10^6 and `len(start)` say between 10^4 and 10^5. Loop performs the operation ~ 5s, however, this operation may need to performed 10^5 times for various`start` vectors making it an unfeasible approach

Comment: Are all entries of `end` at fixed interval from corresponding entries in `start`? Like it is `5H` for the given sample.

Comment: They are @Divakar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Basic Idea

As usual pandas would spend time on searching for that one specific index at `data_series.loc[s:e]`, where `s` and `e` are datetime indices. That's costly when looping and that's exactly where we would improve. We would find all those indices in a vectorized manner with `searchsorted`. Then, we would extract the values off `data_series` as an array and use those indices obtained from `searchsorted` with simple integer-based indexing. Thus, there would be a loop with minimal work of simple-slicing off an array.

General mantra being - Do most work with pre-processing in a vectorized manner and minimal when looping.

The implementation would look something like this -

```
def select_slices_by_index(data_series, start, end):
    idx = data_series.index.values
    S = np.searchsorted(idx,start.values)
    E = np.searchsorted(idx,end.values)
    ar = data_series.values
    return [ar[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(S,E+1)]
```

#### Use `NumPy-striding`

For the specific case when the time-period between `starts` and `ends` are same for all entries and all slices are covered by that length, i.e. no out-of-bounds cases, we can use `NumPy's sliding window trick`.

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

def select_slices_by_index_strided(data_series, start, end):
    idx = data_series.index.values
    L = np.searchsorted(idx,end.values[0])-np.searchsorted(idx,start.values[0])+1
    S = np.searchsorted(idx,start.values)
    ar = data_series.values
    w = view_as_windows(ar,L)
    return w[S]
```

Use [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40085052/) if you don't have access to `scikit-image`.

---

#### Benchmarking

Let's scale up everything by `100x` on the given sample data and test out.

Setup -

```
np.random.seed(0)
start = pd.Series(pd.date_range('20190412',freq='H',periods=2500))

# Drop a few indexes to make the series not sequential
start.drop([4,5,10,14]).reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

# Add some random minutes to the start as it's not necessarily quantized
start = start + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(59,size=len(start)),unit='T')

end = start + pd.Timedelta('5H')
data_series = pd.Series(data=np.random.randint(20, size=(750*600)), 
                        index=pd.date_range('20190411',freq='T',periods=(750*600)))
```

Timings -

```
In [156]: %%timeit
     ...: frm = []
     ...: for s,e in zip(start,end):
     ...:     frm.append(data_series.loc[s:e].values)
1 loop, best of 3: 172 ms per loop

In [157]: %timeit select_slices_by_index(data_series, start, end)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop

In [158]: %timeit select_slices_by_index_strided(data_series, start, end)
1000 loops, best of 3: 994 µs per loop

In [161]: frm = []
     ...: for s,e in zip(start,end):
     ...:     frm.append(data_series.loc[s:e].values)

In [162]: np.allclose(select_slices_by_index(data_series, start, end),frm)
Out[162]: True

In [163]: np.allclose(select_slices_by_index_strided(data_series, start, end),frm)
Out[163]: True
```

**`140x+`** and **`170x`** speedups  with these ones!

Comment: Very nice answer! I didnt think to use `np.searchsorted`

Comment: Excellent answer - I had never come across `np.searchsorted` but it works perfectly for my needs

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the apply function if you move your series into a Dataframe:

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'s': start,'e':end})
pdf.apply(lambda x: data_series.loc[x['s']:x['e']].values, axis=1)
```

Dask can help you parrallelize this computation for big data amounts.

http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply
https://github.com/dask/dask

Comment: `.apply` is just a loop under the hood and should be avoided for row based loops. It's still super slow when `len(pdf)` is large. I was hoping to be pointed in the direction of a proper vectorized solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be vectorized, however another direction worth looking at is IntervalIndex which is designed to handle this kind of indexing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364710/finding-matching-intervals-in-pandas-intervalindex

Answer (score 1):

You can find the indices where elements of `start` and `end` are in `data_series` using `index.get_loc`

```
ind_start = [data_series.index.get_loc(i) for i in start]
ind_end = [data_series.index.get_loc(i) for i in end]
```

Then using [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis) and [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to peform the slice.

```
frm = [np.take_along_axis(data_series.values, np.r_[s,e],axis=0) for s,e in zip(ind_start,ind_end)]
```

using `%timeit`

```
%timeit [np.take_along_axis(data_series.values, np.r_[s,e],axis=0) for s,e in zip(ind_start,ind_end)]
425 µs ± 4.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comparing to the for loop method using `.loc`

```
def timeme(start,end):
    frm = []
    for s,e in zip(start,end):
        frm.append(data_series.loc[s:e].values)

%timeit timeme(start,end)
2.99 ms ± 65.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This does not work - values of `start` may not be in the keys of `grouped` for unquantized data

Comment: Maybe edit the question with `start` to show that case.

Comment: @ojlm Edited my answer